# Story about robots that keep serving extinct humans

Tags: story-identification

I feel like in the past I've come across a (sci-fi?) story where robots/AI are serving extinct humans while being completely oblivious to the fact that the humanity is extinct. It may or may not have taken place in a bunker and/or on another planet. I think there could have been a scene where the AI makes a toast or breakfast in the morning and there is no one to eat it.

I don't remember any other detail and whether it was a book or a movie or something else. I could just be a poster for all I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be *[There Will Come Soft Rains](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40876)* (1950) by Ray Bradbury, which is typically found as a part of his *Martian Chronicles* collection of related stories.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Will_Come_Soft_Rains_(short_story)):

> "There Will Come Soft Rains" is about the operation and destruction of an unoccupied, highly automated house that is the residence of the McClellan family, starting in the waking hours of April 28, 1985 and ending in the morning of the next day.
> [...]
> The narrative then follows the house operating as if it was occupied, including automated announcements, meal preparation, after-meal clean up, bed preparation, house cleaning, yard maintenance, and entertainment. In particular, the house, during the morning prepares the family for a rainy day. The morning routine includes watering an outdoor yard and garden that reveals that a nuclear bomb killed the family, and that the explosion singed the western face of the house except in places where objects were directly in front of it. The singed face captured an image of people, presumably members of the McClellan family, unaware of any danger, at the moment they were incinerated by the bomb blast.

I won't quote further in case you'd like to (re)read the story for yourself - which I highly recommend. It's bleak, but an incredible read. Additionally, it was made into a really interesting Russian animated short, found on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LNHYz89sNc).

Comment: It's also reminiscent of Kryten in Red Dwarf, when the crew first meet him.